# Not able add zoom/pan on scatter plot

Tags: d3.js, scatter-plot

I created a scatter plot using D3.js.I would like to add the functionality to zoom and pan.
I have declare zoom behaviour for scatter plot.Try to use it in svg element.
But it throws error says **argument of type zoom behavior is not assignable to parameter of type selection:selection SVGElement**

I am just a beginner with using D3.Can anyone help or have any suggestions?

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
.scaleExtent([0.3, 2])
.on("zoom", function () {
svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
});    
var svg = d3.select(component).append('svg')
.attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append('g')
.attr("transform",
"translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
.call(zoom);
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

You need to provide a function to the onzoom handler

```
.on("zoom", function () {
  svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
});
```

should look more like this, where you are calling your own function and passing it the transform as a parameter

```
  d3.select(context.canvas).call(d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, 8])
      .on("zoom", () => zoomed(d3.event.transform)));
```

The `zoomed` function could be this:

```
  function zoomed(transform) {
    context.save();
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    context.translate(transform.x, transform.y);
    context.scale(transform.k, transform.k);
    context.beginPath();
    for (const [x, y] of data) {
      context.moveTo(x + r, y);
      context.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    }
    context.fill();
    context.restore();
  }
```

These snippets were taken from this example:

https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoom-canvas

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the approach taken in the question, [example](https://jsfiddle.net/3hc4pg9z/) (*however, there are separate positional issues with the OP's approach to zooming on an SVG, but these won't generate an error*). Using `selection.call(d3.zoom...`, by comparison makes subsequent modifying the zoom a bit more awkward (not applicable in your linked example of course), but otherwise your proposed solution should perform the same as the code in the question - given the error stated I suspect an issue an some underlying framework that expects a certain type for `selection.call`

Comment: Yeah, not being to see the complete code I was a bit in the dark, hence I could only reliably refer to a working example that may not match perfectly